# How to speed up my android app?

Tags: android

In my android application . I am loading the content from web to the activity for 2 to 3 screens

So the application get slow at the time of running and clicking the buttons

Is their any way to speed up my application with quick response to the user in android

Comment: You might also want to watch this official video: [Google I/O 2010 - Writing zippy Android apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4znvD-7VDA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use background thread to download the content, a good and simple way to do that is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). While the download speed depends on the connection, you can give indication to the user using the [onProgresUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) method.